# Why do infants ask for wine in Lamentations 2:12?

Tags: lamentations

Lamentations 2:11-12

> My eyes fail from weeping,
> I am in torment within;
> my heart is poured out on the ground
> because my people are destroyed,
> because children and infants faint
> in the streets of the city.
> They say to their mothers, "Where is bread and wine?"

Why do infants ask for wine? Does this have implications on the Lord's Communion?

Comment: The exact construction וָיָ֑יִן _wayayin_ 'and wine' [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/lamentations/2-12.htm) and [Strong 3196](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/vayayin_3196.htm) seems to occur exactly seven times in scripture which may point to a significance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply said, probably, the expression ‘corn and wine’ (ויין דגן) – like the similar expression ‘bread and wine’ (see, for some examples, Gen 14:18, Judges 19:19, Neh 5:15) - should be intended **an idiom for ‘something to eat, and something to drink’**.

In fact, the scholars Keil & Delitzsch commented the expression (bold is mine): “The children say to their mothers, Where is corn and wine?" **i.e., Give us bread and wine, or, Where can we eat and drink?**”

I hope this answer your question.